# Creating a Keyboard Chord Which Overrides a Default Action (CTRL-V)

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-6.0

My goal is to replicate the keyboard chord combination from Visual Studio editor <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> which duplicates the line. *To be clear, this is not a question on how to duplicate a line, but to handle a keyboard chord scenario in WPF.*

How can a chord be accomplished where

- The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> standalone won't fire the custom line duplication command and just **not be handled** when <kbd>E</kbd> has **not** accompanied it.

  - *AKA fall back to the system to do a Paste.*
  - This is not a deal breaker and I can process the clipboard if so.

---

I've tried

```xml
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+E" Command="{Binding cmdSetChord_E}"/>
<KeyBinding Gesture="Ctrl+V" Command="{Binding cmdDuplicateCurrent}"/>
```

and

```
bool ePressed;

private void tbPatternDesign_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.E)
        ePressed = e.Handled = true;

    if (ePressed && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control && e.Key == Key.V)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
        e.Handled = true;
        ePressed = false;
    }
}
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CommandBinding` to override a control's default command implementation. This is a sample with a `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="EditingCommands.AlignCenter" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
    </TextBox.CommandBindings>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Command="EditingCommands.AlignCenter" Gesture="CTRL+E"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>

    bool ePressed;

    private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (((RoutedUICommand)e.Command).Text)
        {
            case "Paste":
                if (ePressed)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplicate");
                    ePressed = false; 
                }
                else
                    ((TextBox)sender).Paste();
                break;
            case "AlignCenter":
                ePressed = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As an side, my `TextBox` is not supporting `AlignCenter` and I have to capture the first chord (`E`) in Keypress down and then use your override of Paste.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.E) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.V) && ...
```

Comment: The `E` and `V` are not executed at the same time. The control though, will still be held for both. But A keyboard chord (not my name for it) simply signifies a chain of keyboard actions, not necessarily executed at the same time based on the type of key. As a touch typer, I don't hit both keys with my left hand, each key is individual; except for the holding down of the Ctrl.

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
Console.readkey()
```

It might not be the most intuitive way of doing it, but it is a good for-now solution.

Comment: That is what the subscribed to event KeyDown is doing in WPF.

Comment: This solution will in no way work with WPF.